# Meteor Autoform `this.field("keyName").value` returns undefined in Schema

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

I have a `Person` and I want a `fullName` field and value to automatically be created when a person changes their `firstName` or `lastName` fields.

```
People.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
        label: 'First Name'
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
        label: 'Last Name'
    },
    fullName: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
        label: 'Full Name',
        autoValue: function() {
          var firstName = this.field("firstName");
          var lastName = this.field("lastName");

          if(firstName.isSet || lastName.isSet){
                return firstName.value + " " + lastName.value;
            } else {
                this.unset();
            }
          }
    }
}));
```

If I then do

`People.update("ZqvBYDmrkMGgueihX", {$set: {firstName: "Bill"}})`

The `fullName` is set as `Bill undefined`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your condition `firstName.isSet || lastName.isSet` says, if either of `firstName` or `lastName` is available in the document, then create `fullName`. So it is correctly assigning full name, as one of them is set (First Name is set to Bill). You need to use `&&` instead of `||` like this.

```
People.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
        label: 'First Name'
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
        label: 'Last Name'
    },
    fullName: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
        label: 'Full Name',
        autoValue: function() {
            var firstName = this.field("firstName");
            var lastName = this.field("lastName");

            if(firstName.isSet && lastName.isSet){
                return firstName.value + " " + lastName.value;
            } else {
                this.unset();
            }
        }
    }
}));
```

But, based on your question, I think, you want to set `fullName` only when one of `firstName` or `lastName` is updated then, I think (I am not sure), you need to check `this.field('firstName').operator` to check whether it is `$set` in the current operation or not.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. I'm a little confused on what `this.field("someField")` actually refers to. When an object is inserted into `People`, only `firstName` and `lastName` are set. So does `this.field("firstName")` always refer to the value during any kind of `Create` or `Update` operation?

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny yes, `this.field("firstName").value` always refers to the value irrespective of whether it is set during the current operation or previous operation.

Comment: Hmmm, OK, so the function in `autoValue` doesn't need some kind of trigger / event for it to run?

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny `autoValue` will run whenever your schema is `clean`ed.  Cleaning will be done automatically before `Update` or `Insert` or you can clean it by explicitly calling it.